# MySQL - query optimization - order by multiple fields from different joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, inner-join

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT t1.col_A, t2.col_A, t2.col_B
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2.ID = t1.t2_ID
WHERE t1.active = 1
ORDER BY t2.col_A ASC, t2.col_B ASC, t1.col_A ASC
LIMIT 0,100
```

Table t1 indexes:

- id
- col_A
- active
- t2_ID

Table t2 indexes:

- id
- col_A
- col_B

In real life, the tables DO NOT SHARE column names.

The heavy thing here is the `ORDER BY` , without it, query takes 0.001 seconds, with it takes 9 to 10 seconds depending on the size of the table.

I am having a problem identifying how to optimize this query.

Edited as requested, adding `EXPLAIN` output:

[image]

Comment: Post the result of `explain select t1 ...`

Comment: I just added the requested info.

Comment: Can you also post the results of the query plan `Explain Analyse select ..`

Comment: do you have single indexes for all columns of t2 or just one with the combination of the two columns?

Comment: If you are using a composite order on the same table it's better to have a composite index on the columns.

Additionally, a rule of thumb is to add an index on each column referenced in a where, order, group and join clause.

Comment: i suggest to add index on t2 for the combination (col_A,col_B) and it may be useful also another index a part for t1.active column

Comment: @BUcorp I have single indexes, ... but the problem is with `t1` , if I take it out the `ORDER BY ` clause, is fast again. You can also see this in the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: @JunaidAli , thanks for the advice. 

I have the proper indexes.

I do not have the composite index for `t2` , which I have tried, but no positive impact in the query speed.

The problem is with `t1`  included in the `ORDER BY`.

I have updated the post, the index section

Comment: Thanks @BUcorp, I have added the suggsted composite index, but no improvement.

Comment: I have updated the post, for the Index section info. I forgot to add t1.active too.

Comment: Or maybe the query cannot be optimized ... maybe

Comment: update also the explain section. (are these result obtained for the full table or just with 100 rows? Because if it happend only with 100 rows i would like to know what kind of data are in there :D  )

Comment: @BUcorp the `EXPLAIN` section is up to date

Comment: can you create the index on table t2 cola and colb with using asc and check ?  'create index  idx_1 on table_name (col_a asc, col_b asc);

Comment: the mysql version?

Comment: the version is MySQL 5.7 @BUcorp

Comment: To aid in readability, don't unnecessarily reuse column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope it to make a little difference

```
      ANALYZE TABLE t1;
      ANALYZE TABLE t2;
      create index idx_2 on t2 (col_a asc, col_b asc);
      create index idx_1 on t1(col_a asc);
```

Comment: Have you tried them exactly like in this order using composite indexes ?

Comment: I can confirm after double checking, that this did not improved the performance. @Jfrd

Comment: can you post your create index script ? for each table ? its good if you add this to your question too.

Comment: first of all, thanks for helping me. The thing is that this is an already existing database. The indexes are already created, BUT I did what you suggested, your suggested query was executed OK, then I try running my slow query, and speed did not improve.

Answer (score 0):

For this query you want two indexes:

```
SELECT t1.col_A, t2.col_A, t2.col_B
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.ID = t1.t2_ID
WHERE t1.active = 1
ORDER BY t2.col_A ASC, t2.col_B ASC, t1.col_A ASC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The indexes are:

- `t1(active, t2_id, col_a)`
- `t2(id, col_a, col_b)`

The second is not necessary if `id` is a primary key.

Unfortunately, there is no way (short of using a temporary table) to avoid sorting for the `order by`, because it is combining columns from different tables.

Comment: The suggested indexes already exist. So you say that there is no way to improve this?

Comment: @jcmargentina. . . Your question has listed multiple indexes.  This specifically says two indexes with the specified columns in the specified order.

Comment: @jcmargentina - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; 3 indexes with one column each is _not_ the same as 1 composite index, as Gordon is suggesting.